# useEffect is not run on every state change locally, but works in Snack (ReactNative)

Tags: react-native

This is the snack: https://snack.expo.dev/@minifisk/shooting-range-snack

It works as expected in the snack (i.e. the red ball moving everytime I click the opposite button).

However, locally, the ball only moves every 3rd click. I've done a screen recording to show the behaviour along with the console log, to see when the useEffect is called:

https://streamable.com/bzmo74

This is the code I'm running locally (same as the one in the snack, beside the import of the ChoiceButton that is in another directory.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, SafeAreaView, ImageBackground, Image } from "react-native";

import ChoiceButton from "../../components/ChoiceButton";

// import ak4_image from "../images/other/weapons/ak4.png";
// import ak4_kk_image from "../images/other/weapons/ak4kk.png";
// import kpist_image from "../images/other/weapons/kpist.png";
// import ksp58_image from "../images/other/weapons/ksp58.png";

const ShootingDistance = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [targetLayout, setTargetLayout] = React.useState(undefined);
  const [parentContainer, setParentContainer] = React.useState(undefined);
  const [ballPlacement, setBallPlacement] = useState(450);
  const [choosenGun, setchoosenGun] = useState("Kpist");
  const [buttonHiddenSoldier, setbuttonHiddenSoldier] = useState(true);
  const [buttonSoldierInOpen, setbuttonSoldierInOpen] = useState(false);
  const [gunImage, setGunImage] = useState(null);
  const [RangeMode, setRangeMode] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("rangemode useeffect called");
    update_shooting_range();
  }, [RangeMode]);

  const setValueGun = (value) => {
    if (value == 0) {
      setchoosenGun("Ak4");
    } else if (value == 1) {
      setchoosenGun("Ak4 Kikarsikte");
    } else if (value == 2) {
      setchoosenGun("Kpist");
    } else if (value == 3) {
      setchoosenGun("Kulspruta 58");
    }
  };

  const update_shooting_range = () => {
    if (choosenGun == "Ak4") {
      if (buttonHiddenSoldier) {
        setBallPlacement(300);
      } else {
        setBallPlacement(500);
      }
    } else if (choosenGun == "Ak4 Kikarsikte") {
      if (buttonHiddenSoldier) {
        setBallPlacement(400);
      } else {
        setBallPlacement(600);
      }
    } else if (choosenGun == "Kpist") {
      if (buttonHiddenSoldier) {
        setBallPlacement(150);
      } else {
        setBallPlacement(250);
      }
    } else if (choosenGun == "Kulspruta 58") {
      if (buttonHiddenSoldier) {
        setBallPlacement(400);
      } else {
        setBallPlacement(600);
      }
    }
  };

  const updateButtonHiddenSoldier = () => {
    setbuttonHiddenSoldier(true);
    setbuttonSoldierInOpen(false);
    setRangeMode(0);
  };

  const updateButtonSoliderInOpen = () => {
    setbuttonHiddenSoldier(false);
    setbuttonSoldierInOpen(true);
    setRangeMode(1);
  };

  const activateButtonHiddenSoldier = () => {
    updateButtonHiddenSoldier();
  };

  const activateButtonSoliderInOpen = () => {
    updateButtonSoliderInOpen();
  };

  // Create a ref for each view that the green ball can be placed on
  const view1Ref = React.useRef(null);
  const view2Ref = React.useRef(null);
  const view3Ref = React.useRef(null);
  const view4Ref = React.useRef(null);
  const view5Ref = React.useRef(null);
  const view6Ref = React.useRef(null);
  const view7Ref = React.useRef(null);
  const view8Ref = React.useRef(null);
  const view9Ref = React.useRef(null);
  const view10Ref = React.useRef(null);
  const view11Ref = React.useRef(null);
  const view12Ref = React.useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Use the ballPlacement value to determine which view to measure
    if (ballPlacement === 600 && view1Ref.current) {
      view1Ref.current.measure((x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
        setTargetLayout({ x, y, width, height });
      });
    } else if (ballPlacement === 550 && view2Ref.current) {
      view2Ref.current.measure((x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
        setTargetLayout({ x, y, width, height });
      });
    } else if (ballPlacement === 500 && view3Ref.current) {
      view3Ref.current.measure((x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
        setTargetLayout({ x, y, width, height });
      });
    } else if (ballPlacement === 450 && view4Ref.current) {
      view4Ref.current.measure((x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
        setTargetLayout({ x, y, width, height });
      });
    } else if (ballPlacement === 400 && view5Ref.current) {
      view5Ref.current.measure((x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
        setTargetLayout({ x, y, width, height });
      });
    } else if (ballPlacement === 350 && view6Ref.current) {
      view6Ref.current.measure((x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
        setTargetLayout({ x, y, width, height });
      });
    } else if (ballPlacement === 300 && view7Ref.current) {
      view7Ref.current.measure((x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
        setTargetLayout({ x, y, width, height });
      });
    } else if (ballPlacement === 250 && view8Ref.current) {
      view8Ref.current.measure((x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
        setTargetLayout({ x, y, width, height });
      });
    } else if (ballPlacement === 200 && view9Ref.current) {
      view9Ref.current.measure((x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
        setTargetLayout({ x, y, width, height });
      });
    } else if (ballPlacement === 150 && view10Ref.current) {
      view10Ref.current.measure((x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
        setTargetLayout({ x, y, width, height });
      });
    } else if (ballPlacement === 100 && view11Ref.current) {
      view11Ref.current.measure((x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
        setTargetLayout({ x, y, width, height });
      });
    } else if (ballPlacement === 50 && view12Ref.current) {
      view12Ref.current.measure((x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
        setTargetLayout({ x, y, width, height });
      });
    }
  }, [ballPlacement]);

  return (
    <ImageBackground
      source={require("../images/backgrounds/background.png")}
      resizeMode="cover"
      style={{ flex: 1, width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
    >
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, margin: 10 }}>
        {targetLayout && parentContainer && (
          /* Greenball view */
          <View
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "red",
              width: targetLayout.height / 2,
              height: targetLayout.height / 2,
              borderRadius: targetLayout.height / 2,
              position: "absolute",
              zIndex: 2,
              left:
                targetLayout.x +
                parentContainer.x +
                targetLayout.width / 2 -
                targetLayout.height / 2,
              top: targetLayout.y + parentContainer.y + targetLayout.height / 4,
            }}
          />
        )}
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Text
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              color: "white",
              fontSize: 30,
              textAlign: "center",
              marginTop: 20,
            }}
          >
            Skjutavstånd
          </Text>
          <Text
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              color: "white",
              fontSize: 20,
              textAlign: "center",
            }}
          >
            Välj ett vapen samt typ av mål för att se max rekommenderat
            skjutavstånd.
          </Text>
        </View>

        {/* ParentContainer for all views */}
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 2,
            backgroundColor: "lightgray",
            width: "90%",
            marginHorizontal: 20,
            marginTop: 20,
          }}
          onLayout={(event) => {
            const layout = event.nativeEvent.layout;
            setParentContainer(layout);
          }}
        >
          {/* View 1 */}
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              borderColor: "black",
              borderStyle: "solid",
              backgroundColor: "lightgray",
              borderBottomWidth: 1,
            }}
            ref={view1Ref}
          >
            <Text style={{ textAlign: "right" }}>600 meter</Text>
          </View>
          {/* View 2 */}
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              borderColor: "black",
              borderStyle: "solid",
              borderBottomWidth: 3,
            }}
            ref={view2Ref}
          >
            <Text style={{ textAlign: "right" }}>550 meter</Text>
          </View>
          {/* View 3 */}
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              borderColor: "black",
              borderStyle: "solid",
              borderBottomWidth: 1,
            }}
            ref={view3Ref}
          >
            <Text style={{ textAlign: "right" }}>500 meter</Text>
          </View>
          {/* View 4 */}
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              borderColor: "black",
              borderStyle: "solid",
              borderBottomWidth: 3,
            }}
            ref={view4Ref}
          >
            <Text style={{ textAlign: "right" }}>450 meter</Text>
          </View>
          {/* View 5 */}
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              borderColor: "black",
              borderStyle: "solid",
              borderBottomWidth: 1,
            }}
            ref={view5Ref}
          >
            <Text style={{ textAlign: "right" }}>400 meter</Text>
          </View>
          {/* View 6 */}
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              borderColor: "black",
              borderStyle: "solid",
              borderBottomWidth: 3,
            }}
            ref={view6Ref}
          >
            <Text style={{ textAlign: "right" }}>350 meter</Text>
          </View>
          {/* View 7 */}
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              borderColor: "black",
              borderStyle: "solid",
              borderBottomWidth: 1,
            }}
            ref={view7Ref}
          >
            <Text style={{ textAlign: "right" }}>300 meter</Text>
          </View>
          {/* View 8 */}
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              borderColor: "black",
              borderStyle: "solid",
              borderBottomWidth: 3,
            }}
            ref={view8Ref}
          >
            <Text style={{ textAlign: "right" }}>250 meter</Text>
          </View>
          {/* View 9 */}
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              borderColor: "black",
              borderStyle: "solid",
              borderBottomWidth: 1,
            }}
            ref={view9Ref}
          >
            <Text style={{ textAlign: "right" }}>200 meter</Text>
          </View>
          {/* View 10 */}
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              borderColor: "black",
              borderStyle: "solid",
              borderBottomWidth: 3,
            }}
            ref={view10Ref}
          >
            <Text style={{ textAlign: "right" }}>150 meter</Text>
          </View>
          {/* View 11 */}
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              borderColor: "black",
              borderStyle: "solid",
              borderBottomWidth: 1,
            }}
            ref={view11Ref}
          >
            <Text style={{ textAlign: "right" }}>100 meter</Text>
          </View>
          {/* View 13 */}
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              borderColor: "black",
              borderStyle: "solid",
              borderBottomWidth: 3,
              flexDirection: "row",
              justifyContent: "space-between",
            }}
            ref={view12Ref}
          >
            <Text style={{ flex: 1, textAlign: "right" }}>50 meter</Text>
          </View>
        </View>

        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
          }}
        >
          <Text style={{ flex: 1, color: "white", fontSize: 22 }}>
            Välj vapen (4)
          </Text>
          <Text
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              color: "white",
              fontSize: 14,
              color: "yellow",
              fontWeight: "bold",
            }}
          >
            {choosenGun}
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
          }}
        >
          <Text style={{ flex: 1, color: "white", fontSize: 28 }}>
            Typ av mål
          </Text>
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              flexDirection: "row",
              justifyContent: "space-between",
              marginBottom: 20,
            }}
          >
            <ChoiceButton
              ClickFunction={activateButtonHiddenSoldier}
              ButtonState={buttonHiddenSoldier}
              ButtonText="Soldat i värn"
              MarginRight={10}
            />

            <ChoiceButton
              ClickFunction={activateButtonSoliderInOpen}
              ButtonState={buttonSoldierInOpen}
              ButtonText="Soldat öppet"
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </ImageBackground>
  );
};

export default ShootingDistance;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was some not updated dependencies for react slider, so after I fixed those and restarted my simulator, things were working as they should again.